# How to exchange square bracket and curly bracket (karabiner)

Tags: karabiner

On Karabiner rules (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/), there is a rule for `Exchange paren and square bracket` but there is no rule for `Exchange square bracket and curly braket`.

**[Q]** How to exchange square bracket and curly bracket through `Karabiner` or any alternative?

Wanted exchange:

- `[` => `{` and `{` => `[`
- `]` => `}` and `}` => `]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me

```
{
  "description": "Swap {} and []",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "open_bracket"
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "modifiers": ["left_shift"],
          "key_code": "open_bracket"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "open_bracket",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_shift"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "open_bracket"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "close_bracket"
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "modifiers": ["left_shift"],
          "key_code": "close_bracket"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "key_code": "close_bracket",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_shift"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "close_bracket"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

edit: also now in complex mod list https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#exchange_square_brackets_and_curly_brackets

Comment: In which file should I paste this?

Comment: This has been merged to the complex rules list. you can search it there now :)

Comment: edited my answer to link to the new rule i submitted

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering is it possible to use these rule only for `U.S.` keyboard, and disable them if another keyboard is selected? I can ask it under a different question.

Comment: i think it's possible although i haven't tried it yet. go ahead and ask it and i'll do my best to figure it out

Comment: Also is it possible to exchange dash and underscore as well? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329484/how-to-exchange-dash-and-underscore-karabiner

Comment: For my other question please see => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329520/is-it-possible-to-enable-rules-only-for-specific-keyboard-layout-karabiner