# How to exchange dash and underscore (karabiner)

Tags: karabiner

On Karabiner rules (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/), there is no rule for `Exchange dash and underscore`.

**[Q]** How to exchange dash and underscore through `Karabiner` or any alternative?

Wanted exchange:

- `-` => `_` and `_` => `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it exists in karabiner's complex modification list. See here: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#exchange_hyphen_and_underscore

They just call it hyphen and not dash