# How to enable rules only for specific keyboard layout (karabiner)?

Tags: keyboard, key-bindings, karabiner

On Karabiner I am enabling multiples rules under its complex modifications setup, such as `Emacs key bindings`.

I was wondering is it possible to use those enables rules only for a specific keyboard layout such as `U.S.` and automatically disable those rules when I switch to an another keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [guide](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2272#issuecomment-627583083)

> Take a look at the [device_if example](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/example.html) and the [Conditions documentation](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/complex-modifications-manipulator-definition/conditions/)

---

I added following code into `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`

```
{
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "input_sources": [
                        {
                            "language": "en"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "input_source_if"
                }
            ],

            "from": {
                "key_code": "open_bracket"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "open_bracket",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "input_sources": [
                        {
                            "language": "en"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "input_source_if"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "close_bracket",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "close_bracket"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "input_sources": [
                        {
                            "language": "en"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "input_source_if"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "close_bracket"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "close_bracket",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "input_sources": [
                        {
                            "language": "en"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "input_source_if"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "open_bracket",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "open_bracket"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to turn existing imported rules to be device specific. However if you make or modify those rules you can.

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html#condition-definition-device

The gist of how to make your own rules is making a json file inside

```
~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/
```

You can name the json file whatever you want. you can even symlink it from another place if you prefer.

So if you have a rule you want to make device specific, copy paste it inside your json file and modify it from `type: "basic"` to to `type: "device_if"` and fill up your device id etc. which you can get from the Karabiner EventViewer app under devices tab.

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work :( The link you provide is not working.

Comment: Should I open this as an issue on Karabiner's github page?